# Customize icons in a grub theme

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, linux-mint, themes

First of all, I don't know if this is the right place to post, so I'm sorry if it isn't.

I have installed a theme ([tela](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1307852/)) to the grub bootloader, and it adds icons to OS entries. Is there any way I can assign icons to entries manually? For example, the Linux Mint entry is displayed with the Ubuntu icon, I would like to change that.

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I see I'm not getting any replies. Please could you tell me where do I have to ask this question if this is not the right place? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the grub knows what icons to load is by first looking at your `menuentry`s and `submenu`s (usually in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in ubuntu derivatives) and looking for the `--class something` property, then it looks at your current theme folder (in your case probable in `/boot/grub/themes/Tela`) any icons called `something.png` and uses that file, so you should add your png icons there and the `--class` attribute in your `grub.cfg`.

But there is a catch, every so often the `grub.cfg` file is updated and anything you manually modified will be gone, in particular whenever there is a system upgrade it will be overwritten.

For this I will make a shameless plug of a grub theme/tool of mine: [Matter](https://github.com/mateosss/matter/) inspired in the same set of themes where Tela theme came from. Matter solves the problem mentioned above by modifying the `update-mkconfig` command, which is the one that updates the grub, so when the grub is updated, matter runs some replacements on the `grub.cfg` file to put the user icons back there.

Comment: Could you explain how your tool prevents overwriting manually made changes